# Getting a specific column when one element of thead is selected using QuerySelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, markdown

Hi Im displaying a table via Markdown (inside of React) so Im styling it using querySelectors innerHtml but what I want to do is when user selects one of the given options in thead (I have already extracted them in separate array) that the column with the coresponding thead will change color of the text

Here is an example:

[image]

When I select `option1` which is inside thead I want the `column11, column12 and column13` to change colors

Here is how I retrieved the list of elements inside tbody:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr > td').forEach((bodyContent) => {
      console.log(bodyContent.textContent);
    });
```

What I print out is column, column11, column21, column31, column, column12...

Any help would be great

Comment: AFAIK, there's no native way to select a table column by the header. However, you'll obtain an array after executing `querySelectorAll`, say it's array `Cells`. Try to find out the pattern of indexes that is in the column to highlight, and access the target cells using indexes.
For example, *option1* is the 2nd header, so you're looking for the 2nd column. `Cells[1]`, `Cells[5]` and `Cells[9]` will be the cells to highlight. A math deal.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let prevCol = null;

const options = document.querySelectorAll('thead th');
options.forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const index = option.cellIndex;
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll(`tbody td:nth-child(${index + 1})`);
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.classList.add('selected'));
    if (prevCol !== null) {
      const prevCells = document.querySelectorAll(`tbody td:nth-child(${prevCol + 1})`);
      prevCells.forEach(cell => cell.classList.remove('selected'));
    }
    prevCol = index;
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```